# This LaTeX code executes now but PDF file is not generated? Please help me

Tags: floats, templates, floatrow, endfloat, els-cas

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=below, margin=1cm, labelfont=bf, labelsep=period, skip=12pt, justification=justified}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\let\labelindent\relax
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\restylefloat*{figure} %% create a line before and after an image
\floatstyle{plain}
\captionsetup{labelsep=space,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=on}
\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lineno}
\setlength\columnsep{25pt}

\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp = \\#1\let\\ = \temp}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\centering}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedright}p{#1}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\twocolumn
%% %%%%%%
%%% Packages to add the vertical line with in algorithm:pseudocode
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% start with some helper code
% This is the vertical rule that is inserted
\newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{%
    \makebox[#1][l]{%
        \hspace*{.2em}% <------------- This is where the rule starts from
        \vrule height .75\baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip
    }
}

\newcount\ALG@printindent@tempcnta
\def\ALG@printindent{%
    \ifnum \theALG@nested>0% is there anything to print
    \ifx\ALG@text\ALG@x@notext% is this an end group without any text?
    % do nothing
    \else
    \unskip
    % draw a rule for each indent level
    \ALG@printindent@tempcnta=1
    \loop
    \algrule[\csname ALG@ind@\the\ALG@printindent@tempcnta\endcsname]%
    \advance \ALG@printindent@tempcnta 1
    \ifnum \ALG@printindent@tempcnta<\numexpr\theALG@nested+1\relax
    \repeat
    \fi
    \fi
}
% the following line injects our new indent handling code in place of the default spacing
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\noindent\hskip\ALG@tlm}{\ALG@printindent}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\item[]\nointerlineskip}{}{}{} % no spurious vertical space
% end vertical rule patch for algorithmicx
\makeatother
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have removed the code formatting which makes your question very hard to read

Comment: please do not edit the question asking a completely different question after answers have been posted. It makes the site impossible for later readers to understand. If you want to ask a new question then post a new question. Clearly your posted document makes no pdf as it has no text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bring this to an end please see the following minimalized code:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}


\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I only added command `\listfiles` to get an list of used packages and version numbers at the end of the resulting log file:

```
*File List*
  cas-sc.cls    2018/09/22, 1.0: Formatting class for CAS single column articles
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
   fleqn.clo    2016/12/29 v1.2b Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
 amsmath.sty    2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
   expl3.sty    2019-04-21 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-04-21 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2019-03-05 L3 Experimental document command parser
etoolbox.sty    2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
makecell.sty    2009/08/03 V0.1e Managing of Tab Column Heads and Cells
   array.sty    2018/12/30 v2.4k Tabular extension package (FMi)
multirow.sty    2019/01/01 v2.4 Span multiple rows of a table
colortbl.sty    2018/12/12 v1.0d Color table columns (DPC)
   color.sty    1999/02/16
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 dcolumn.sty    2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)
stfloats.sty    2017/03/27 v3.3 Improve float mechanism and baselineskip settings
  xspace.sty    2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
 xstring.sty    2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
footmisc.sty    2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
dvipsnam.def    2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
  svgnam.def    2016/05/11 v2.12 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
hyperref.sty    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
cas-common.sty    
moreverb.sty    2008/06/03 v2.3a `more' verbatim facilities
verbatim.sty    2014/10/28 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
 wrapfig.sty    2003/01/31  v 3.6
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
    stix.sty    2018/04/17 v1.1.3-latex STIX fonts support package
textcomp.sty    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
  ts1enc.dfu    2018/10/05 v1.2f UTF-8 support for inputenc
geometry.sty    2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
geometry.cfg
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ls1stix.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX LS1 font definitions
 ls2stix.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX LS2 font definitions
  t1stix.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX T1 font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
  488234.out
  488234.out
  t1cmss.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
ls1stixscr.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX script LS1 font definitions
ls2stixex.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX extentions LS2 font definitions
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
ls1stixfrak.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX fraktur LS1 font definitions
ls1stixbb.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX blackboard LS1 font definitions
ls2stixcal.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX calligraphic LS2 font definitions
ls1stixsf.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX sans-serif LS1 font definitions
ls2stixtt.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX typewriter LS2 font definitions
 ***********
```

The compile run with my current MiKTeX 2.9 and used class `cas-sc.cls    2018/09/22, 1.0` ends with the following error message:

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \@begindocumenthook ...\@afterindentfalse \bibsep 
>                                                   =0pt\gdef \bibfont {\fonts...
> l.89 \begin{document}
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

That shows that this version of the class is buggy and needs to be corrected/rewritten by its maintainer.

Based on the list of used packages I showed you you do not need to call for example package `textcomp`, `graphicx`, `amssymb` etc.

Because you did not tell us which version of class `cas-sc` you are using I can not tell you how to correct the buggy class. Best would be to ask the maintainer/owner of that class to correct it!

Comment: This happens because the class requires to (but does not) load `natbib`. Loading `natbib` makes this(!) problem disappear. Which does not mean the class works.

Comment: The manual does say the class depends on `natbib`, but if it is mandatory the class should do it. Counts as a bug in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

The error in full is

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Presumably because the class has already loaded xcolor, so you could delete

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

There is a similar error

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package amsmath.
```

Comment: They also load `float` at least three times.

Comment: @Teepeemm although that is just untidy it doesn't actually do any harm, later ones are ignored.

Comment: When I removed \usepackage[table]{xcolor}. Then error  \usepackage{url} is generated.

Comment: @GhulamHafeez No! that error is the amsmath one that I gave, look in the log file at the actual error message, if you are using an editor that is just showing the error as ` \usepackage{url} ` that is most unhelpful. In both cases the error is on the line above. as the actual error message makes clear.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I removed \usepackage[table]{xcolor} and \usepackage{amsmath} but it generates other errors. Please help me

Comment: @GhulamHafeez do you _really_ use all those packages? the preamble looks like it has been cut and pasted from multiple documents, there are clashing loads, repeated `\usepackage` etc, I would strongly recommend deleting the entire preamble and then just add packages if you need them .

Comment: I required these packages, however, I follow your recommendation and check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93003/discussion-between-ghulam-hafeez-and-david-carlisle).